# Ensuring a Java Filter is called ina Grails project

Tags: grails, filter

If I had a Groovy filter, I just have to ensure it is in grails-app/conf/ and end with filters and Groovy will pick it up.  No extra configuration required. But say I'd a Java Filter to my grails project. It implements the Filter interface and is in src/java/com/me/filters but it doesn't get picked up.

What do I need to do to ensure it gets picked up?  In Java I updated the Web.xml.  What do I do in grails.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Run `grails install-templates` and make the change in `src/templates/war/web.xml`